A Polynomial Representation of $\mathbf{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$
It is well known that $\mathbf{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but it can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$: see e.g. Real Projective Plane.
I am wondering whether we can find a diffeomorphic image of $\mathbf{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ which is the solution set of a system of polynomial equalities and inequalities in the four coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^4$.
Thank you very much in advance for your attention.

Let $S^2 = \{ (u,v,w) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : u^2+v^2+w^2=1 \}$ and let $\Psi:S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ be the map defined for any $(u,v,w) \in S^2$ by
$$
\Psi(u,v,w)=(u^2 - v^2,  2uv, uw ,vw).
$$
It is easy to see that $\Psi(u,v,w)=\Psi(\bar{u},\bar{v},\bar{w})$ if and only if $(u,v,w)=(\bar{u},\bar{v},\bar{w})$ or $(u,v,w)=-(\bar{u},\bar{v},\bar{w})$. Remeber now that $\mathbf{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ is the quotient of $S^2$ by the equivalence relation $(u,v,w) \sim -(u,v,w)$, so that, if $\Phi:S^2 \rightarrow \Psi(S^2)$ is the map induced by $\Psi$ and $p:S^2 \rightarrow \mathbf{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ is the natural map, there exists a continuous, bijective map $\tilde{\Phi}:\mathbf{P}^2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \Psi(S^2)$ such that $\tilde{\Phi} \circ p = \Phi$. Moreover, since $\mathbf{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ is compact, $\tilde{\Phi}$ is closed and so a homeomorphism.
By considering coordinates $(u,v)$ (respectively $(u,w)$ and $(v,w)$) on the open sets $\{ (u,v,w) \in S^2 : w > 0 \}$ and $\{ (u,v,w) \in S^2 : w < 0 \}$ (respectively $\{ (u,v,w) \in S^2 : v > 0 \}$  and $\{ (u,v,w) \in S^2 : v < 0 \}$ , and $\{ (u,v,w) \in S^2 : u > 0 \}$ and $\{ (u,v,w) \in S^2 : u < 0 \}$) of $S^2$, it is easy to check that $\Psi$ is an immersion. Now, if $\iota:\Psi(S^2) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ is the inclusion, we have $\iota \circ \Phi = \Psi$, so that $\iota \circ \tilde{\Phi} \circ p = \iota \circ \Phi = \Psi$, and being $p$ a local diffeomorphism, we get that $\iota \circ \tilde{\Phi}$ is an immersion too. In conclusion $\iota \circ \tilde{\Phi}$ is an embedding, so that $\mathbf{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ is diffeomorphic to $\Psi(S^2)$ through $\tilde{\Phi}$.
Now, let $P$ be the set of all $(x,y,z,t) \in \mathbb{R}^4$ satisfying the following system
\begin{equation}
(S) \qquad \left\{
\begin{array}{llll}
x^2+y^2 &= (x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2)^2 \\
y(z^2-t^2) &= 2xzt\\
x(z^2-t^2) &\geq  0 \\
yzt &\geq0.  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
We claim that $P=\Psi(S^2)$. First of all let us show that $\Psi (S^2) \subseteq P$. Let
\begin{align}
x &= u^2 - v^2 \\
y &= 2uv \\
z &= uw \\
t &= vw \\
\end{align}
for some $(u,v,w) \in S^2$.
From the first two equations we get $x^2+y^2=(u^2+v^2)^2$, while from the last two equations we get $z^2+t^2=(u^2+v^2)w^2=(u^2+v^2)-(u^2+v^2)^2$, so that $z^2+t^2=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} - (x^2+y^2)$, from which we get the first equation of $S$. Moreover, we also have $y(z^2-t^2)=2uv(u^2-v^2)w^2=2xzt$, that is the second equation of $S$. The first inequality of $S$ come from $x(z^2-t^2)=(u^2-v^2)^2 w^2  \geq 0$, while the second derives from $yzt=2u^2 v^2 w^2 \geq 0$. So $\Psi (S^2) \subseteq P$.
Conversely, let $(x,y,z,y) \in P$. Consider the system
\begin{equation}
(\Sigma) \qquad \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
x &= u^2 - v^2 \\
y &= 2uv. \\
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
Clearly if $(u,v)$ is a solution of $\Sigma$, also $-(u,v)$ is. By squaring both sides of the two equations of $\Sigma$ and summing up, we get $x^2+y^2= (u^2 + v^2)^2$, so that
$$
(i) \qquad \sqrt{x^2+y^2}= u^2 + v^2.
$$
From this equation and the first equation of $\Sigma$ we get $2u^2=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x$ and $2v^2=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x$, hence the solutions are
$$
(ii) \qquad  u=\pm \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}{2}},\\ 
(iii) \qquad v=\pm \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x}{2}},
$$
where the two equations have to be taken with the same sign if $y > 0$ and with opposite signs if $y < 0$ (when $y=0$ we have either $u=0$ or $v=0$, and the way in which we match the signs is immaterial). To fix the values of $u$ and $v$, let us take both equations with the plus sign when $y \geq 0$, while we take the first with the plus sign and the second with the minus sign for $y < 0$.
Now note that the first equation of $S$ is equivalent to $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2$, from which we get $z^2+t^2=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} - (x^2+y^2)=(u^2+v^2)(1-u^2-v^2)$. This shows that $u^2+v^2 \leq 1$, so that, by defining $w=\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2}$, we can write
$$
(iv) \qquad z^2+t^2= (u^2+v^2)w^2.
$$
Now let us consider first of all the case $y=0$, so that we have $uv=0$ from the second equation of $\Sigma$ and $xzt=0$ from the second equation of $S$. If also $x=0$, then from (i) and (iv) we get $u^2+v^2=0$ and $z^2+t^2=0$, so that $u=v=z=t=0$, and we can of course write $z=uw$ and $t=vw$, so that $(x,y,z,t)=\Psi(u,v,w)$. If instead $x \neq 0$ we must have $zt=0$. In particular, if $x > 0$ (respectively $x < 0$), we get $v=0$ from (iii) and $z^2 \geq t^2$ from the first inequality of $S$ (respectively $u=0$ from (ii) and $z^2 \leq t^2$ from the first inequality of $S$), so that $t=0=vw$ and $z= \pm uw$ by equation (iv) (respectively $z=0=uw$ and $t= \pm v w$ by equation (iv)). Hence we have $(x,y,z,t)=\Psi(u,v,w)$ or $(x,y,z,t)=\Psi(u,v,-w)$.
Now consider the case $z=0$. From the second equation of $S$ we get $y(z^2-t^2)=0$. If $y=0$ we are in the case above. If instead $y \neq 0$, we must have $z^2=t^2$, so that $t=z=0$. Since $2uv=y \neq 0$, from equation (iv) we get also $w=0$, so that we can write $z=uw$ and $t=vw$, that is $(x,y,z,t)=\Psi(u,v,w)$.
The case $t=0$ is dealt with analogously. Finally consider the case in which $y,z, t$ are all distinct from zero. Since $2uv=y \neq 0$, both $u$ and $v$ are distinct from zero. By defining $\alpha=z/t$ and $a=u/v$, from the second equation of $S$ we get
$$
\alpha-\frac{1}{\alpha}=a-\frac{1}{a},
$$
which has the two solutions $\alpha=a$ and $\alpha=-1/a$. If $\alpha=-1/a$, then we would have $yzt= 2uvzt= 2 a v^2 \alpha t^2= -2v^2 t^2 < 0$ against the last inequality of $S$. So we must have $\alpha=a$, that is $z/t=u/v$. From the latter equation and equation (iv) we get $z^2=u^2w^2$ and $t^2=v^2w^2$, so that
$$
z=\pm uw,\\
t=\pm vw,
$$
where both equations hold with the plus sign or both with the minus sign by the last inequality of $S$. Hence we get again $(x,y,z,t)=\Psi(u,v,w)$ or $(x,y,z,t)=\Psi(u,v,-w)$. This shows that $P \subseteq \Psi(S^2)$. QED
NOTE 1 You may wonder whether $\mathbf{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ can be described by using only a couple of polynomial equalities, but this is not possible. More generally, the non-orientability of $\mathbf{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ implies that it cannot be described as the solution of an equation $f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{0}$ for some smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$: see here.
NOTE 2. We can replace $S^2$ by the generic 2-sphere $S_{r}= \{ (u,v,w) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : u^2+v^2+w^2=r^2 \}$ for some $r >0$ and again consider the equivalence relation $(u,v,w) \sim -(u,v,w)$, so that $S_{r}/ \sim$ still gives $\mathbf{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$. Then by defining the map $\Psi:S_{r} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ as before:
$$
\Psi(u,v,w)=(u^2 - v^2,  2uv, uw ,vw),
$$
and by proceeding exactly as above we see that the set $P$ of all $(x,y,z,t) \in \mathbb{R}^4$ satisfying the system
\begin{equation}
(S) \qquad \left\{
\begin{array}{llll}
r^4(x^2+y^2) &= (x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2)^2 \\
y(z^2-t^2) &= 2xzt\\
x(z^2-t^2) &\geq  0 \\
yzt &\geq0.  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
is a diffeomorphic image of $\mathbf{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$.
NOTE 3. There is a very similar representation of (the diffeomorphic image of) the Klein bottle in $\mathbb{R}^4$: see my answer here.

I have created this post in order to share with all the community this little, but interesting fact!
